# CSS - how to avoid class= for every single paragraph?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a CSS like this:

```
p {
        color: #000000;
}

p.myclass {
        color: #ff0000;
}
```

So all paragraph text should be black except for "myclass" paragraphs, which are red.

What I see is that if I do this:

```
<div class="myclass">
<p>Something something something</p>
</div>
```

I still get black.  If I do this:

```
<p class="myclass">Something something something</p>
```

Then I get red.

On the real-world page, I have multiple sections that I want to apply different classes to, so I can't just define 'p' at the page level.  But class= for each

tag seems really inefficient.

Isn't there a way to say "in this block, use this class, and then any

tags in that block match that class?  I thought that's what div did.

I'm sure there's something basic I'm misunderstanding...

Comment: I believe this question is more suited on stack overflow rather than Webmasters (Voted for migration).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `.myclass p`  in your css. The benefits of having DIV is that you can style the box and then style p afterwards.

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```
<p>This is a content in black</p>
<p>This is more content in black</p>
<div class="myclass">
    <p>This content is in red</p>
    <p>This more content in red</p>    
</div>    
<p>This is content again in black</p>
```

**CSS EXAMPLE**

```
.myclass p {color:red;}
p {color:black;}
```

**ONLINE EXAMPLE**

Check out this [JS Fiddle I made for you which demonstrates](http://jsfiddle.net/652Jk/) use of myclass with p. A more advanced demo can be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/652Jk/1/) which demonstrates the use of span styling with in a p tag and styling the DIV as a box within the container.